# How to pass parameter to previous page using INavigationAware Back button

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, viewmodel

I am having problem using INavigationAware codes. I have 3 pages. For example I named it pageA, pageB and pageC. PageA is a list view and I will pass the parameter to pageB using OnItemSelected

**PageA View Model**

```
public void OnItemSelected(Complaint item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                var param = new NavigationParameters();
                param.Add("id", item.Id);
                mNavigationService.NavigateAsync("pageB", param);
            }
        }
```

In pageB, i will get the parameter using OnNavigatedTo.

**PageB View Model**

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            var id = parameters["id"];
            Title = string.Format("{0}: {1}", Strings.ComplaintDetail_Title, id);
            await getComplaintDetail(Convert.ToInt32(id));

        }
```

From pageB, I will send the parameter to pageC using the same way. But right now, I am having problem with passing the parameter back to pageB. Since I am using INavigation Back button on the left top, I don't know how to pass the parameter back to pageB. The issue is I need to pass the parameter (primary key) to all pages for select and update purposes. Please help me. I'm not sure how to pass the parameter using OnNavigatedFrom.

**PageC View Model**

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a service? If the current item has to be known to all pages anyway, making it available "globally" might be an alternative to passing it around all the time.

Comment: How to make it global? Sorry I'm totally a newbie.

Comment: Through a service that's available to all your view models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to state the obvious, but have you tried adding to the parameters collection in the OnNavigatedFrom method?

```
    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        parameters.Add("test", "testValue");   
    }
```

Comment: OnNavigatedFrom is not called when calling GoBackAsync, this happens only on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I Use Xamarin.Essentials SecureStorage to achieve this result, Just insert your value into SecureStorage with a key then get it again when needed :

Save your parameter when you navigate to PageB :

```
SecureStorage.SetAsync("current_id", YourParameterValue);
```

When back to BageB in your OnAppearing event (override the event) get value from SecureStorage :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {

            base.OnAppearing();
            var CurrentId = long.Parse(  SecureStorage.GetAsync("current_id").Result);
            this.BindingContext = new PageBViewModel(CurrentId) ;
        }
```

Assuming that your Id is a long.

Note : i am not sure this is the clean way to do it but it works.